# See/document include, require, include_once etc. in Doxygen

Tags: php, doxygen

Has anyone found out how to let Doxygen document includes, requires, include_once and require_once?

I'm using Doxygen 1.1.8 with dot/graph wiz.

tnx!

Comment: "Document" how? What result do you expect?

Comment: I want to be able to see which files are included an a particular file, and also, how often a file has been included, similar to how  you can see how often a particular function is called.
Of course, it would be very brilliant if all included could be shown in a graph.

Comment: This will not work if you use an autoloader and I think most bigger project use them. If you use the oop style, doxygen shows you which class is used by other classes. Since every class should be containd in its own file, this would be just what you are looking for.